# I want mouse hover effect on buttonimage of datepicker

Tags: php, jquery-ui-datepicker

following is my code,

```
$(".datepicker'.$k.'").datepicker({
                     changeMonth: false,
                     showOn: "button",
                     buttonImage: "themes/assets_en/image/calanderimages.png",
                     buttonImageOnly: true,
                     buttonText: "Click it..",
                     changeYear: false,
                     changeDate: true,
                     startDate: "'.date('m/d/Y',strtotime($default_startdate)).'",
                     endDate: "'.$end_dt.'",
                     //dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                     maxDate: "'.$end_dt.'",
                     //maxDate: +4,
                     minDate: "'.$start_dt.'",
                     '.$beforeShowDay.'
                     onSelect: function(date) {
                        $(".datepicker'.$k.'").val($("#datepicker-re'.$k.'").val()); 
                     }
         })
```

Now i want is that when we mouse hover the button image of calendar at that time datepicker should be display .
Currently when i click on button image of calendar datepicker is displaying. i dont want this. 
plz guys help me in this.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why do you want something to just pop up. I might be scrolling over multiple datepickers and all of them will open up at the same time? I think a lot of people will just leave your page if you implement such features.

Comment: hello@DainisAbols i want mouse hover effect on button image

Comment: when i hover over a particular button image at that time 1 date picker should be display.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer.

```
$("#datepicker1_'.$k.'").datepicker({
                     changeMonth: false,
                    // showOn: "button",
                    // buttonImage: "themes/assets_en/image/calanderimages.png",
                    // buttonImageOnly: true,
                    // buttonText: "Click it..",
                     changeYear: false,
                     changeDate: true,
                     startDate: "'.date('m/d/Y',strtotime($default_startdate)).'",
                     endDate: "'.$end_dt.'",
                     //dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                     maxDate: "'.$end_dt.'",
                     //maxDate: +4,
                     minDate: "'.$start_dt.'",
                     '.$beforeShowDay.'
                     onSelect: function(date) {
                        $(".datepicker'.$k.'").val($("#datepicker-re'.$k.'").val()); 
                     }
         })
         .hide()



$("#datepickerImage<?php echo $k;?>").hover(function() {
         $("#datepicker1_<?php echo $k;?>").toggle(); 
         // /$("#datepicker").show(); 
     });

<img src="themes/assets_en/image/calanderimages.png"  id="datepickerImage<?php echo $k;?>" class="calendar_img">
                        <div id="datepicker1_<?php echo $k;?>"></div>
```